# Is onnx computational graph static or dynamic?

Tags: optimization, graph, neural-network, onnx, onnxruntime

As mentioned in the onnxruntime documentation:

```
Out of the box, ONNXRuntime applies a series of optimizations to the ONNX graph, combining nodes where possible and factoring out constant values (constant folding).
```

My question is:

```
Is the exported ONNX computational graph a static graph or a dynamic one?
```